# Black output of animation render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I have a VFX video project that consists of two scenes that are linked together with complex *Compositing*. I want to render the whole animation, but after rendering both scenes, Blender does compositing that turns everything into a black picture. However, the compositing isn't the issue because when I render any single frame, everything works right and I can see the anticipated result. I don't change anything in between; I just press the *Render* or *Animation* button. Using Cycles.

This is a screenshot of a frame rendered as a part of animation.
[image: Black output]

This is a screenshot of the very same frame rendered separately.
[image: Normal output]

You can see that both have already gone through compositing so the problem has to be somewhere in difference of *Still* and *Anim* rendering.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are a number of things that might be wrong, not the least of which is "nothing" ;-) Can you be a bit more specific about what you're seeing that's black, and what you're seeing that's okay? And WHERE you're seeing that? It's entirely possible that everything is rendering correctly, but that the Image Viewer is showing a black image as part of the compositing process. Upload a screenshot of the pane where you're seeing black. There's a simple setting that might fix what you're seeing.